# How to create an array of objects and acess the functions inside the subclass? c++

Tags: c++, class

To capture images simultaneous I want to create an array of objects (`cam`). With the current array I can execute the functions of the `class xiAPIplus_Camera` but the functions inside the `class xiAPIplusCameraOcv : public xiAPIplus_Camera` won't start.
e.g:If I start `cv::Mat         GetNextImageOcvMat();` the class destructor runs instead.

```
class xiAPIplusCameraOcv : public xiAPIplus_Camera
{
public:
    /**
    * Initialize the xiAPIplusCameraOcv class.
    */  
    xiAPIplusCameraOcv();
    /**
    * Class destructor. Free allocated memory, release images
    */
    virtual ~xiAPIplusCameraOcv();
    /**
    * Reads an image from the camera using XiAPI, stores the image in OpenCV Mat format.
    * @return OpenCV Mat image. 
    */
    cv::Mat         GetNextImageOcvMat(); //Reads an image and converts it to OpenCV Mat
    /**
    * Converts a XiAPI image (xiAPIplus_Image*) to OpenCV Mat.
    * @param input_image[in] Input xiAPIplus_Image* to be converted.
    * @return converted OpenCV IpliImage* image. 
    */
    cv::Mat         ConvertOcvMat(xiAPIplus_Image * input_image); //Converts an image to OpenCV Mat
    //virtual xiAPIplusCameraOcv& operator >> (CV_OUT Mat& input_image);
    
    private:
    
    /**
    * Resets the Opencv image if properties of XI_IMG have changed. Resets the cv_mat_image_.
    */
    void resetCvImage_();               //Resets the OpenCV image properties if XI_IMG format has changed
    cv::Mat                 cv_mat_image_;
    xiAPIplus_Image *   next_image_;      
    int                 timeout_;
    int             counter_;
    int             index_;
};
```

The main function is able to create the array but I am missing something while using it.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        xiAPIplusCameraOcv cam[5];
        int n = cam[4].GetNumberOfConnectedCameras();
        
        int uidArray[4];
        char* snArray[4];
        
        for (int id = 0; id < n; id++)
        {
            printf("Opening %d. camera ...\n", id + 1);
            cam[id].OpenByID(id);
            cam[id].GetSerialNumber(sn, 100);
            
        }
        for (int exp = 0; exp < n; exp++)
        {
            cam[exp].StartAcquisition();
            
            Mat cv_mat_image = cam[exp].GetNextImageOcvMat(); //
            printf("GetNextImageOcvMat\n");

            cv::imwrite(save_at, cv_mat_image);// , compression_params);

            cam[exp].StopAcquisition();
        }

        printf("Done\n");

        cv::waitKey(500);
    }
    catch (xiAPIplus_Exception& exp)
    {
        printf("Error:\n");
        exp.PrintError();
#ifdef WIN32
        Sleep(2000);
#endif
        cv::waitKey(2000);
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

After this line  `Mat cv_mat_image = cam[exp].GetNextImageOcvMat();` the destructor is closing my camera object.

```
/**
* Class destructor. Free allocated memory, release images
*/
xiAPIplusCameraOcv::~xiAPIplusCameraOcv(){
    printf("Closing xiAPIplus_Ocv camera\n");
    cv_mat_image_.release();
}
```

Comment: Have you got your indexing right? You created an array of 5 "cameras". Then you loop over this array based on "n" which is extracted from some method on the 4th "camera". And you are re-using "exp", which is not illegal but doesn't make your code any easier to read. If you aren't indexing into cam[] correctly, you might (depending on the definition of "xiAPIplus_Exception") throw an exception, so ending up in the catch() block, at which point the cam[] array goes out of scope, and each item's destructor is called. Maybe put the "xiAPIplusCameraOcv cam[5];" line outside the try/catch block?

Comment: helpful, i didn't notice that i re-used "exp". But as you said this did't cause the Error. The xiAPIplus_Exception raises and it made no change to put the  "xiAPIplusCameraOcv cam[5];" outside my try/catch block

Comment: Question: what do you think "n" is set to? Does this line: Mat cv_mat_image = cam[exp].GetNextImageOcvMat(); throw an exception which is caught? If so, then there is a problem in the implementation code somewhere (which we cant see).

Comment: n is set to 4. Okay if so i will try to find it out by myself because i dont want to post this much of code here. If someone want to see it : https://www.ximea.com/support/documents/4